# Structure of ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Determine the structure of the ring $R_0$ obtained from $\mathbb{Z}$ by adjoining an element $\alpha$ satisfying each set of relations:
>   $$
> \begin{cases}
> 2x-6 &= 0\\
> x-10 &=0
> \end{cases}
> $$

I know that the solution is just $\mathbb{Z}/14$. I am struggling to reach that conclusion.

I understand that finding a linear combination and setting this equal to zero, we find that $$2x-6-2(x-10)=14=0,$$ so we much be in $\mathbb{Z}/14$.

What I am confused about now is how $2x-6$ and $x-10$ simply just go away? Any help on this would be great. Thanks

Comment: Do not  ask the [same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771794/adjoining-elements-to-a-ring-4) again.

Comment: I saw the other post and I see this one now: how can an infinite ring to which is been *added* an element and relations become a **finite** ring? Besides the doubt that I am missing something, could be we're simply taking a quotient (homomorphic image) of the ring $\;\Bbb Z\;$ by adding some relations to some of its generators?